# how to fetch the data of each excel row into html templates?

Tags: python, html, django, excel, templates

I need to uplaod an excel file in Django. Then i want to fetch certain values from each row of excel and paste it in html template.
This process needs to be repeated till whole of the excel rows finish.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pandas and plug them to a div element through a separate view(AJAX).

```
pip install pandas
```

Note: Answer applies assuming you want to read through backend

```py
import pandas as pd

# If you're new to python help yourself - https://pandas.pydata.org/

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABCD'))

for i in range(0,5):
    df.loc[i] = [i, i+1, i+2, i*i]
    
print(df)

print(df.to_html())
```

Comment: I want to import data from Excel sheet, as i mentioned.